# How do I iterate through an array of structs?

Tags: c, pointers

I have this hashmap I want to implement.

```
typedef void * Data;

typedef struct {
    Data data;                  //Data pointer to the data
    char * key;                 //char pointer to the string key
} HashMapItem;

typedef struct hashmap {
    HashMapItem * items;        //items of the hashmaps
    size_t size;                //size of the hashmaps
    int count;                  //how many elements are in the hashmap
} HashMap;
```

I declare it like so:

```
HashMap * create_hashmap(size_t key_space){
    if(key_space == 0)
        return NULL;
    
    HashMap * hm = malloc(sizeof(HashMap));                                     //allocate memory to store hashmap
    hm->items = calloc(key_space, sizeof(HashMapItem));          //allocate memory to store every item inside the map, null it
    hm->size = key_space;                                                       //set sitze of hashmap
    hm->count = 0;                                                              //empty at the begining


    return hm;
}
```

When i try to iterate through it, it says that
**expression must have arithmetic or pointer type but has type "HashMapItem"** even though i declare it as a pointer of HashMapItems

```
 if((hm->items)[index] != NULL)
```

Any idea?

Comment: HashMap *hm = (HashMap *)malloc(sizeof(HashMap)), try something like this but look at the doc for malloc to make you're using correctly, and provide the entire code so we can run it better help you resolve issues.

Comment: We probably need to see more of your code. You just posted `(hm->items)[index]` but I'm guessing you did something like: `HashMapItem *current = (hm->items)[index];` If so, that is dererencing the contents and you want a _pointer_: `HashMapItem *current = &hm->items[index];` (note the `&`)

Comment: @MZM casting pointers is not the sollution

Comment: @CraigEstey why does your sollution work?

Comment: It's the difference between getting the _data_ of a desired array element vs a _pointer_ to the desired array element. What you did was the equivalent of `int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };` and then `int current = array[1]; printf("%d\n",current);` What I did was the equivalent of: `int *current = &array[1]; printf("%d\n",*current);` Both will print `2` Actually, what you did was: `int *current = array[1];`, so the compiler complained. because we tried to put an `int` value into a _pointer_ variable.

Comment: Note that in `a & b`, the `&` is the "bitwise and" operator. With `int x = 23; int y = &x; printf("%d %d\n",x,*y);` it's the "address of" operator [both numbers printed will be `23`].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef void * Data;
```

Never hide pointers behind typedefs. It is a very, very bad practice.

How to iterate.

```
typedef struct {
    void *data;                  //Data pointer to the data
    char * key;                 //char pointer to the string key
} HashMapItem;

typedef struct hashmap {
    HashMapItem * items;        //items of the hashmaps
    size_t size;                //size of the hashmaps
    size_t count;                  //how many elements are in the hashmap
} HashMap;


void foo(HashMap *map)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < map -> count; i ++)
    {
        puts(map -> items[i].key);
    }
}
```

PS `count` member should be also `size_t`

EDIT. Below is wrong as `hm->items)[index]` has type `HashMapItem` and it is not **pointer**. You cant compare it to NULL.

```
 if((hm->items)[index] != NULL)
```

Comment: why should the count be size_t? it says how many items are in the array

Comment: @CristianCutitei for the same reason as `size`. Why is `size` `size_t` not `int`?

Comment: because its an unsigned integer?

Comment: @CristianCutitei so why is it not `unsigned int`?  BTW can `count` be negative?